# Adding a bootstrap button removes all previous CSS positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried adding a bootstrap button to my webpage and it shifted all the elements to the left side of the page.

I have tried changing the position of the button.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button" id = 'backbtn'>Back</a>
```

I was trying to get the button to just appear on the screen without it affecting any of the other elements but right now it appears on the screen but shifts all other things to the left of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all put your custom css stylesheet after the bootstrap. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_custom.css">
```

So your CSS overwrites anything that was styled before. Also try using !important at the end of css calls like - float: right !important; and if this doesn't help either just use another class name for the button and style it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing happen when your existing class overlap any class of bootstrap.So, first check if you had used any class which was already declared in bootstrap.

Secondly, you can use a div for all content of your website and use a class named "container".

```
<div class="container">
    //your contents
</div>
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: There is no other class with that name and adding a div around all content did not do much.